# using list in turtle in python

Tags: python, list, colors

I did not understand the following line  -

'i = random.randint(0, **len(colors)-1**)' (Highlighted with ############)
in the following code:

```
import  turtle
import random


colors = 
["red","green","blue","yellow","orange","black","purple","gray","maroon"]
turtle.penup()

for i in range(200):
    x = random.randint(-100,100)
    y = random.randint(-100,100)

    #set a random position
    turtle.setpos(x,y)

    #set a random color
    ############
    i = random.randint(0, len(colors)-1) 
    ############
    turtle.dot(colors[i])
```

Moreover, whats wrong if I write
i = random.randint(0, len(colors))
instead of
i = random.randint(0, len(colors)-1)
??

thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you mean len(colors)-1 ?
Think that len(colors-1) has nonsense

Comment: I suggest that you read the manual. it's random value pickup in a range.

Comment: The code is incorrect as you have written it (the `-1` should be outside the innermost parentheses like this `random.randint(0, len(colors)-1)`), and there is a much simpler way to do it in Python anyway (`random.choice(colors)`), and anyway SO is for asking about how to fix your own code, not for understanding someone else's.

Comment: `len(colors-1)` will give you this error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
i = random.randint(0, len(colors)-1)
```

It picks a random Color btwn 0 and the length of the color array -1 (to stay in its boundries).

Answer (score 0):

change and try this,

```
i = random.randint(0, len(colors)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
i = random.randint(0, len(colors)-1) 
turtle.dot(colors[i])
```

Take advantage of the `choice()` function in random:

```
turtle.dot(random.choice(colors))
```

This avoids the opportunity for the original error as no indicies nor math are involved:

```
>>> import random
>>> help(random.choice)
Help on method choice in module random:

choice(seq) method of random.Random instance
    Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence.
```